# Inserting Data in sql database vb.net is not getting stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, insert

I have a weird problem: I'm trying to do some basic procedure to insert data in a database and I don't know what it's happening, but it does not work.

The thing is that I have a database called `prova3` that is a SQL Server 2012 database created with vb.net 2013 with a table called `tabela`. I created a dataset to see the connection string that is stored in `app.config`. The string is the same below. I'm not getting an error, but the data is not inserted. When I go to the Server explorer to see the data in the table, it's empty.

I think the data it's been saved in elsewhere, but I don't know how to fix it, because I think I'm coding this right. This is for vb.net, but I did the same code for asp.net and it works. Weird.

Could you help me?

In the form it's only a textbox1 and a button1 controls. There is no more code.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ImageUrlSt As String
    Dim command1 As New SqlCommand
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    ImageUrlSt = TextBox1.Text
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Prova3.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        command1.Connection = con
        command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tabela (imageurl) VALUES (@imageurlst)"
        command1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@imageurlst", ImageUrlSt))
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("News Saved Succesfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Table` the name of your table? It is an SQL keyword, how did you use that name for your table?

Comment: Sorry, I copied a bad version of the code. The name of the table is Tabela, and in the code is tabela too. I edited the code. thanks for noticing it

Comment: The message box is shown?

Comment: Yes, the message it's shown

Comment: Does your textbox have any value? I mean did you enter any data in it?

Comment: yes, i type some letters before click button1

Comment: Did you try having breakpoints in your code? They might show you any exceptions which occur

Comment: I even did "step by step", but it seems all normal, but the data is not iserted in the database. I read in another thread that the problem could be that the program store the data in the bin/debug database, and not in the database of the stringconnection, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: this is all the code of the program and this code works for me in aspx.net

Comment: check the returncode of ExecuteNonQuery to see if a record was inserted ... should be one in this case

Comment: Sometimes `|DataDirectory|` as path is problematic when debugging. Did you check the db copy at `\bin\debug`?

Comment: I checked the returncode of executenonquery assigning a variable to it, and the result is "true", so it means that a record was inserted, true? But where? Ho I go through the problem of [DataDirectory]? Is there another way to do this? To tell the program where to find de database locally don't telling the entire path. I'm very thankful for all of your help, guys!

Comment: Well, I checked the database copy at \bin\debud, and YES, the data is inserted there. How can I resolve this situation? I mean, is it supposed to be this way (to insert data in \bin\debug database) or the program must insert the data in the original database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `|DataDirectory|` as path is problematic when debugging. Did you check the db copy at `\bin\debug`?

There’s a property `Copy to Output Directory` and the default value is `Copy if newer` (if you’re using .mdf or .mdb file, the default value is `Copy always`). You could check this **[MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx)** to learn what this property means. In short, the local database file will be copied to Output directory, and THAT database is the one that will get updated.

If you don’t want Visual Studio to copy the database file for you, you could set the Copy to `Output Directory` property to `Do not copy`. Then it’s your choice when and how to overwrite the database file. Of course, you still need two copies of database file: at design time, you’re using the database file in solution directory, while at run time, you’re modifying the one in output directory.

Another option is to use an absolute path at ConnectionString like 
`con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyProjectFolder\Prova3.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`